# Stub a method from tested class to test another method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, stub, stubbing

I discovered that stub and mock are very helpful in testing.
But I wondering about one thing. I think an example will show it clearly.

```
Class A {
    public function isOk() {
        // some work
    }

    public function iAmDepend() {
        if ($this->isOk()) {
            // do work
        }
    }
}

class TestA {
    public function testIsOk() {
        // Test itOk here
    }

    public function testIAmDepend() {
        mock(A)->method(isOk)->return(true);
        // tests for iAmDepend
    }

}
```

It wise to do something like this? Stub method of tested class. Or maybe it breaks some rules?

PS. I can't refactore code

Comment: Dependencies in unit testing terminology are usually regarded as other *classes* on which a class depends, not *methods* within the same class. In your example, you would typically mock both methods of Class A and provide this as a mocked dependency of another class (e.g. classB) which you would test with your unit test.

Comment: You described usual situation. But I am wondering about unusual. Should I understand your statement as discouraging this method of testing? Maybe it is important, in PHP I can choose what methods I want to stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are correct, i.e. `testIsOk` tests only `IsOk`, and `testIAmDepend` only `IAmDepend`.

But there is important difference between mock and stub that you have to understand: [difference between mock and stub](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs).

In your example, if `testIAmDepend` is verifying that `isOk` has been called with some arguments and this is part of your assertion for unittest, this is *mock*. Otherwise this is *stub*, and you aren't going to verify that it has been called or not.

Comment: Ok, so here I'm stubbing :) Thanks for answer. I'm wondering if someone will agree with your opinion.

Comment: For example, `RhinoMock` and other .Net mock frameworks have concept of **partial mock**. Using it you could create object of _CUT_ (class under test), define stubs or mocks for some of method, and then assert behaviour of CUT in some conditions. Thus you could mock work with external resources or dependencies and assert only error handling. Exactly as in your example.

Comment: The only reason why I see this is valid is because you are testing both public methods in this case, and let's say for instance that the method you are currently stubbing is private, that this will have some code smell since stubbing a private method is a bad practice. I learn this the hard way. Also I would recommend from stubbing the the class being tested completely. You should be able to unit test your class without stubbing methods of the same class.